# Where can I find my java installation when where java gives nothing?

Tags: java, installation

It's definitely installed, I can run Minecraft. But I'm trying to run a .jar file and Windows 11 is asking "How do you want to open the file?" And java compiler doesn't show up. btw I've treid where java, it said java didn't exist on the computer

UPDATE: I solved the problem but not the issue, there were some mods that were incompatible with eachother

Comment: I'm pretty sure Minecraft ships with its own Java runtime. And I doubt that runtime will be on your path. Besides, other applications should not use Minecraft's copy of Java. Most likely the solution is for you to actually install a JRE if you're trying to run an executable JAR file, or a JDK if you're _developing_ Java software. One vendor that supplies both JDKs and JREs is [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find it out via printing your PATH.

On Windows: Open the command line via
`Start` -> `CMD`

Paste in

```
echo %PATH%
```

There you should be able to find the java path. Otherwise try to search for JRE.

By the way it is not always 100% sure that you have the java runtime and java compiler installed.
JRE = Java Runtime Environment for executing .jar
JDK = Java Development Kit for compiling java files and creating .jar files

Comment: it says "C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\;C:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"